# Definition of valid partner in Stable Matching Problem

Tags: algorithms, matching

From Tardos and Kleinberg's *Algorithm Design*, the definition for "worse valid partner" is basically — $m$ is $w$'s worse valid partner if $m$ is a valid partner of $w$, and no man whom $w$ ranks lower than $m$ is a valid partner of hers. (page 11 in case anyone has the pdf/book)

Is this a typo? Shouldn't it be "no man whom $w$ ranks higher" or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: Books have typos. Unfortunately it is impossible to tell without more context. If everything makes sense once you correct the typo, then it's probably a typo.

Comment: Did the book say "worst" and you wrote "worse"?  The difference is important.  If you're confused by what the book is saying and you are copying down what the book is saying, I suggest you make sure to copy it accurately, to give us the best chance to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, it's right. A woman w's best valid partner is m where m is a valid partner and no man w ranks higher than m is a valid partner.

A woman w's worst valid partner is m where m is a valid partner and no man w ranks lower than m is a valid partner.